# How can I change maximum available heap size for a task in FreeRTOS?

Tags: embedded, malloc, heap-memory, freertos, keil

I'm creating a list of elements inside a task in the following way:

```
        l = (dllist*)pvPortMalloc(sizeof(dllist));
```

dllist is 32 byte big.
My embedded system has 60kB SRAM so I expected my 200 element list can be handled easily by the system. I found out that after allocating space for 8 elements the system is crashing on the 9th malloc function call (256byte+).

If possible, where can I change the heap size inside freeRTOS?
Can I somehow request the current status of heap size?
I couldn't find this information in the documentation so I hope somebody can provide some insight in this matter.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"The total amount of available heap space is set by `configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` - which is defined in `FreeRTOSConfig.h`."* http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html (Memory Management).

Comment: @WeatherVane: That depends on the memory allocator he uses. Last time I looked at those, there were 4 different types (and none matched the project's requirements).

Comment: @Weather Vane: Thank you the setting combined with the functions that Richard mentioned lead me to the solution, I increased the heap size to 25 kB and now its running smoothly. One interesting thing I observed is that increasing the STACK size of the task increases the available HEAP size also. I wonder about the reason for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Yes - FreeRTOS pvPortMalloc() returns void*.)

If you have 60K of SRAM, and configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE is large, then it is unlikely you are going to run out of heap after allocating 256 bytes *unless* you had hardly any heap remaining before hand.  Many FreeRTOS demos will just keep creating objects until all the heap is used, so if your application is based on one of those, then you would be low on heap before your code executed.  You may have also done something like use up loads of heap space by creating tasks with huge stacks.

heap_4 and heap_5 will combine adjacent blocks, which will minimise fragmentation as far as practical, but I don't think that will be your problem - especially as you don't mention freeing anything anywhere.

Unless you are using heap_3.c (which just makes the standard C library malloc and free thread safe) you can call xPortGetFreeHeapSize() to see how much free heap you have.  You may also have xPortGetMinimumEverFreeHeapSize() available to query how close you have ever come to running out of heap.  More information: http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html

You could also define a malloc() failed hook (http://www.freertos.org/a00016.html) to get instant notification of pvPortMalloc() returning NULL.

Comment: I'm not using demo code and I'm not doing ant other allocations, my code is using heap_4, and it's freeing memory also but I don't think fragmentation will be a problem after 4x32byte mallocs. I will use xPortGetFreeHeapSize() and report back after doing that, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks using the functions I could find out the real problem (See my comment below my question if you wonder) :)

Answer (score 2):

For the standard allocators you will find a config option in FreeRTOSConfig.h .

**However:**
It is very well possible you run out of memory already, depending on the allocator used. IIRC there is one that does not free() any blocks (free() is just a dummy). So any block returned will be lost. This is still useful if you only allocate memory e.g. at startup, but then work with what you've got.

Other allocators might just not merge adjacent blocks once returned, increasing fragmentation much faster than a full-grown allocator.

Also, you might loose memory to fragmentation. Depending on your alloc/free pattern, you quickly might end up with a heap looking like swiss cheese: Many holes between allocated blocks. So while there is still enough free memory, no single block is big enough for the size required.

If you only allocate blocks that size there, you might be better of using your own allocator or a pool (blocks of fixed size). Thaqt would be statically allocated (e.g. array) and chained as a linked list during startup. Alloc/free would then just be push/pop on a stack (or put/get on a queue). That would also be very fast and have complexity O(1) (interrupt-safe if properly written).

Note that normal malloc()/free() are not interrupt-safe.

**Finally:** Do not cast `void *`. (Well, that's actually what standard `malloc()` returns and I expect that FreeRTOS-variant does the same).

Comment: I'm using the alloc function from heap4 which should prevent fragmentation, especially if the system only allocated a few blocks of memory before crashing. In fact, I'm using a linked list for my memory blocks.

Comment: A normal allocator cannot prevent fragmentation actually, but only reduce, unless you do not release or unly use a single block size. For the latter a pool would be easier and faster. However, I just had a look at the available allocators and wrote my own. Mostly because I use the MPU in Cortex-M and need naturally aligned blocks as well as word-aligned.